# Trigger AWS CloudWatch Event Manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a event in CloudWatch, which is triggered once a day. Is there a way to trigger the event manually (for testing purposes)?

...I realize I can increase the frequency of the event's triggering schedule.

Comment: triggers what? if it is lambda then the solution might be easier.

Comment: I want to trigger the event itself to ensure the permissions granted to it and the wiring to the thing it calls (a step function) is correct. I’ve already run the step function independently to test its flow.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have a cloudwatch alarm set up, using the AWS CLI you can, for testing purposes, set the alarm state of that alarm:

```
aws cloudwatch set-alarm-state --alarm-name "myalarm" --state-value ALARM --state-reason "testing purposes"
```

see the [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/set-alarm-state.html)

Alternatively you can [put a custom event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-events.html), also using the CLI or the SDKs

Comment: I'm not triggering the event from an alarm. It's being triggered from a schedule. But, semantics aside, this is a helpful workaround. This is similar (in intent/idea) to adjusting the schedule for the event.

Comment: is there a way to do this via the UI?

Comment: @MetinDagcilar you can trigger the alarm using https://aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/.   it will open a terminal in the browser without any further configuration

Answer (score 8):

Another solution I found is to disable then re-enable the rule:

```
aws events disable-rule --name "my_scheduled_rule"
aws events enable-rule --name "my_scheduled_rule"
```

Perhaps not the best route but an option...

Comment: This won't work in the case of a schedule (i.e. once a day at a specific time). This only works if the event rule is set up as a CRON to run every X minutes for example.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found (and I don't think it is possible) a way to trigger a scheduled trigger manually. But as danimal mentions you can put a custom event to trigger it.

```bash
# update your rule to trigger on a dummy-event source
# put-rule updates a rule if it exists or creates a new one if it doesn't
aws events put-rule --name "my-rule" --event-pattern "{\"source\":[\"karlanka\"]}"
    
# send an event with the same dummy source to trigger the rule
# Detail and DetailType are required but not used
aws events put-events --entries '[{"Source":"karlanka","DetailType":"X","Detail":"{}"}]'
    
# then change the rule back to your schedule
aws events put-rule --name "my-rule" --schedule-expression "rate(12 hours)"
```

Comment: Note, if you try to automate these in a script, you may need to pause the script for 5 seconds between the first put-rule and put-events